# Laravel 5.1 Return a view from a class into the controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have the following controller:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
  public function getTestView() {
      return view("user::index");
  }
}
```

Instead of returning the view directly from my controller method I would like to
have another object which is responsible to return this view after adding some calculation code.

This is my class:

```
class User extends AbstractPerson {

    function __construct() {    
       $this->initView();
    }

    private function initView(){
      return view('user::index');
    }
}
```

My controller now looks like this:

```
 class MyController extends Controller {
     public function getTestView() {
         return new User();
     }
 }
```

After calling this I get the following error:

> UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 395: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: What is this convention you're using to pass the view location? 'user::index'?

Answer (score 0):

Try following what the exception is telling:

```
    class User extends AbstractPerson {

    function __toString() {    
       return $this->initView();
    }

    private function initView(){
      return view('user::index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding user::index   .. user is the folder in the view section and index is the blade file. I tried return $this->initView(); But it still doesn't work

Comment: @Steve normal convention would be 'user.index'. I was not aware of using "::". Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I use the modular package https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular/blob/master/README.md where user:: defines the package name and index the file

Comment: @Steve ok, try this new approach ^^^^

Answer (score 0):

a controller should return a response object, you are just returning a new User object.

```
class MyController extends Controller {
   public function getTestView() {
       User u = new User();
       return u->initView();
   }
}
```